# dynamically created buttons are not working externaly loaded swf files in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a swf file which is a framework file done in puremvc and i m loading multiple swf files. one of the swf file loaded into the main swf file loads multiple sub swf files in it. works fine but in the loaded swf file which loads multiple swf files in it.. button dosent work at all. i m not able to click on any button. i m jst making a tree structure so can be easily understood..

container swf -> external swf -> miniSwf file and in miniSwf dynamic button are not clickable but they have all the Mouse eventListeners.

Answer (score 0):

Do MOUSE_OVER / MOUSE_OUT events work on the buttons at all?

Sounds like it could either be that your parent SWF files have objects in them which cover the buttons, or you could be setting the "mouseChildren" and "mouseEnabled" properties of one of the parent SWFs to false?

Try explicitly setting mouseChildren and mouseEnabled to true on the parent containers and see if that helps?